# Different (much worse) query plan when using one view

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, view, postgresql-12

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT m.entityid,
    m.alias::text AS alias,
    m.measurement_ts,
    m.volume_m3::double precision AS volume_m3,
    m.pressure_mca,
    m.battery_volt,
    (m.volume_m3 - lag(m.volume_m3) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts))::double precision / NULLIF(date_part('epoch'::text, m.measurement_ts - lag(m.measurement_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts)), 0::double precision) * 3600::double precision AS flow,
    (m.volume_m3 - lag(m.volume_m3) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts))::double precision AS volumedelta,
    date_part('epoch'::text, m.measurement_ts - lag(m.measurement_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts)) AS seconds_since_last
   FROM openiot_json.all_pde_data m
where measurement_ts BETWEEN '2021-01-18T20:00:31.69Z' AND '2021-04-18T19:00:31.69Z' and alias = '1002149751'
order by "measurement_ts" desc
```

And that query runs fine, with the following execution plan:

```
Sort  (cost=936.08..936.67 rows=236 width=112) (actual time=64.371..64.749 rows=4334 loops=1)
  Sort Key: addt.measurement_ts DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 802kB
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=912.03..926.78 rows=236 width=112) (actual time=51.539..62.264 rows=4334 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=912.03..912.62 rows=236 width=68) (actual time=51.514..51.867 rows=4334 loops=1)
              Sort Key: ((pts.sid)::text), addt.measurement_ts
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 802kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13.03..902.73 rows=236 width=68) (actual time=1.992..45.831 rows=4334 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using ppe_to_sigfox_alias_sid_start_date on ppe_to_sigfox pts  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=56) (actual time=0.031..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((alias)::text = '1002149751'::text)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on all_devices_data_table addt  (cost=12.76..892.07 rows=237 width=48) (actual time=1.955..43.490 rows=4334 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((entityid = (pts.sid)::text) AND (measurement_ts >= pts."startDate") AND (measurement_ts <= pts."endDate") AND (measurement_ts >= '2021-01-18 21:00:31.69+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (measurement_ts <= '2021-04-18 21:00:31.69+02'::timestamp with time zone))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=3803
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on all_devices_data_table_etdesc  (cost=0.00..12.70 rows=237 width=0) (actual time=1.520..1.520 rows=4334 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((entityid = (pts.sid)::text) AND (measurement_ts >= pts."startDate") AND (measurement_ts <= pts."endDate") AND (measurement_ts >= '2021-01-18 21:00:31.69+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (measurement_ts <= '2021-04-18 21:00:31.69+02'::timestamp with time zone))
Planning Time: 0.636 ms
Execution Time: 65.103 ms
```

So far, so good. Now, if you look at the original query, you can see some computed metrics in the `SELECT` list which I don't want to keep copying and pasting around. So I create a `VIEW` that does this for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW openiot_json.measurement
AS SELECT m.entityid,
    m.alias::text AS alias,
    m.measurement_ts,
    m.volume_m3::double precision AS volume_m3,
    m.pressure_mca,
    m.battery_volt,
    (m.volume_m3 - lag(m.volume_m3) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts))::double precision / NULLIF(date_part('epoch'::text, m.measurement_ts - lag(m.measurement_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts)), 0::double precision) * 3600::double precision AS flow,
    (m.volume_m3 - lag(m.volume_m3) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts))::double precision AS volumedelta,
    date_part('epoch'::text, m.measurement_ts - lag(m.measurement_ts) OVER (PARTITION BY m.entityid ORDER BY m.measurement_ts)) AS seconds_since_last
   FROM openiot_json.all_pde_data m;
```

Now, if I try the same query again, but against the view:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    openiot_json.measurement
WHERE
  measurement_ts BETWEEN '2021-01-18T20:00:31.69Z' AND '2021-04-18T19:00:31.69Z' and alias = '1002149751'
ORDER by measurement_ts desc
```

I get a much worse performance, because the query plan changes:

```
Sort  (cost=123776.16..123777.61 rows=581 width=112) (actual time=18810.436..18810.910 rows=4334 loops=1)
  Sort Key: measurement.measurement_ts DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 802kB
  ->  Subquery Scan on measurement  (cost=104880.52..123749.48 rows=581 width=112) (actual time=18385.000..18808.447 rows=4334 loops=1)
        Filter: ((measurement.measurement_ts >= '2021-01-18 21:00:31.69+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (measurement.measurement_ts <= '2021-04-18 21:00:31.69+02'::timestamp with time zone) AND (measurement.alias = '1002149751'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2152725
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=104880.52..119621.90 rows=235862 width=112) (actual time=12030.287..18600.273 rows=2157059 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=104880.52..105470.18 rows=235862 width=68) (actual time=12030.232..13001.832 rows=2157059 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: ((pts.sid)::text), addt.measurement_ts
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 160488kB
                    ->  Gather  (cost=1017.07..74155.19 rows=235862 width=68) (actual time=29.601..817.669 rows=2157059 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          Workers Launched: 2
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=17.07..49568.99 rows=98276 width=68) (actual time=21.239..517.195 rows=719020 loops=3)
                                Hash Cond: (addt.entityid = (pts.sid)::text)
                                Join Filter: ((addt.measurement_ts >= pts."startDate") AND (addt.measurement_ts <= pts."endDate"))
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3001
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on all_devices_data_table addt  (cost=0.00..32967.84 rows=884484 width=48) (actual time=0.041..147.070 rows=707600 loops=3)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=10.92..10.92 rows=492 width=56) (actual time=21.029..21.031 rows=496 loops=3)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 53kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on ppe_to_sigfox pts  (cost=0.00..10.92 rows=492 width=56) (actual time=20.783..20.898 rows=496 loops=3)
Planning Time: 1.008 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 55
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 10.280 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 3.027 ms, Emission 58.193 ms, Total 71.500 ms
Execution Time: 18882.123 ms
```

Looking at the query plans, the first query is first filtering rows, then sorting. However, the second query is first sorting (which takes a lot of time cause it sorts on disk) and then filtering.

Why is this and how can I fix it, so that I get the nice query plan and performance using the view?

Just as a note, the `openiot_json.all_pde_data` used in the original query is also a `VIEW`, which uses tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW openiot_json.all_pde_data
AS SELECT pts.sid::text AS entityid,
    pts.alias,
    addt.recvtime,
    addt.measurement_ts,
    addt.volume_m3 + pts."offset" AS volume_m3,
    addt.pressure_mca,
    addt.battery_volt,
    pts."offset"
   FROM openiot_json.all_devices_data_table addt
     JOIN openiot_json.ppe_to_sigfox pts ON addt.entityid = pts.sid::text AND addt.measurement_ts >= pts."startDate" AND addt.measurement_ts <= pts."endDate";
```

I am using the following version:

> PostgreSQL 12.4 (Debian 12.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
> compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two queries are **not equivalent**.

The first query without view runs window functions ***after*** applying the `WHERE` clause.
The second query on the view runs window functions ***before*** applying the `WHERE` clause.

This can lead to different results. And (obviously) to different query plans.

Your second view `peniot_json.all_pde_data` does not use window functions (or any other features) that would have a similar effect.

Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query as laid out here:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

Comment: I see, interesting. Is there a way to use that (or a similar) view so that I don't have to repeat the expressions in the SELECT, but get the results of the first query?

Comment: You'll need a function for that. Or a prepared statement.